# Search patterns with awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to search all .csv files for this certain pattern:

[name],[surname],[+][2 numbers][space][phone number]

For example some valid examples could be :

John,Smith,+32 2243547690

Taylor,James,+30 2325447301

Comment: Please show us what have you tried, so we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: I have tried this but it's only for the name sed -n '/[a-z]/,/,/p' *.csv

Comment: Please put what you have tried into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something to start with:-

```
awk -F, '$1~/^[a-zA-Z]+$/&&$2~/^[a-zA-Z]+$/&&$3~/^\+[0-9][0-9] [0-9]+$/' file.csv
```